# How to update one table with multiple row value

Tags: php, mysql

in my case i did both INSERT & UPDATE becoz i made a condition that if a voter has already voted, it will just update his info on my tbl_initialVote table. else if not, it will insert. how can i do this in an update format. pls help... just ignore the redundancy of variable $voter.. thnks.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `tbl_initialVote` (`studId`, `candId`) 
                VALUES ('".$voter."', '".$chairman."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$vchairman."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$secretary."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$treasurer."')")
```

to Peterm

```
//this $getinfo is base on the logged in user
 $getinfo = $mysqli->query("SELECT studId FROM`tbl_initialVote` WHERE studID = '".$voter."'"); 
    if ($getinfo->num_rows > 0 ){
          //here i know it got me error on this but this just i want to happen, make an update in the table if the user is already listed on my table. how could i suppose to do like this...@Peterm.    
              $mysqli->query(UPDATE `tbl_initialVote` set candId = VALUES('".$chairman."', '".$vchairman."', '".$secretary."', '".$treasurer."')

              } else {
       $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `tbl_initialVote` (`studId`, `candId`) 
                VALUES ('".$voter."', '".$chairman."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$vchairman."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$secretary."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$treasurer."')")

                   }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your requirements and illustrate it, including desired output, with some sample data?

Comment: @peterm.. i updated my posted codes.. hope u could find me an answer.. thnks in advance..

Comment: Sorry, it didn't make it any clearer. Does the `tbl_initialVote` table have other columns? How you distinguish between chairman and treasurer once you inserted your data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: can u pls have me an example? base on your link i cant get how could i do it on my part..plss

Answer (score 0):

Google searched "update table with multiple row value php"

Yielded this result: http://snipplr.com/view/20334/

I hope this helps, bro!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, and I'm still struggling to understand it, IMHO you can simply sequentially do `DELETE` and then `INSERT` your new records and don't care about update.

That way all your code boils down to this:

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `tbl_initialVote` WHERE `studId`='" .$voter. "'");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `tbl_initialVote` (`studId`, `candId`) 
                VALUES ('".$voter."', '".$chairman."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$vchairman."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$secretary."'), 
                       ('".$voter."', '".$treasurer."')");
```